# Kubuntu 16.04 - Touchpad not working

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad

I installed Kubuntu 16.04 on my laptop but I don't get my touchpad to work. However it does work on live-boot from usb, but not on the installed system. 
`xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` is already installed and the touchpad is not disabled through my laptop (or at least toggling enable/disable does not help).

How can I make it work again?

EDIT:
It was requested to show the output of the `xinput`-command:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse           id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Primax Kensington Eagle Trackball         id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

It looks like it can't even find my touchpad.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have similar issue. At some moment I found out that my touchpad wasn't working. I tried toggle it on/off, reboot, update. Running `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` showed no touchpad devices.

After a while accidentally I toggled touchpad to enabled (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Fx</kbd>) on the lock screen after reboot and it started working.

I'm not sure what it was, but you can try it. Now running `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` shows my touchpad.